# Running a loop from bottom to top

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I've got the following code but need it to run from bottom to top to keep the order the same from the prior sheet, but can't figure out how to do it. Everything I try seems to break the code. Thanks!

```
Sub Insert()
    Dim dc As Range
    With Sheets("All")
        For Each dc In Intersect(.Range("D:D"), .UsedRange)
            If dc.Value2 = 780101 Then
                dc.Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("780101").Rows(6).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the simplest way would be to convert it to a for loop and for from lastRow to 1 step -1.

Comment: I'm a little new to VBA how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to find the last row and then work up from there.  This should get you close:

```
Sub test()
Dim lr As Long, _
    rowCounter As Long

    With Sheets("All")
        lr = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For rowCounter = lr To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rowCounter, 4).Value = 780101 Then
                .Cells(rowCounter, 4).Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("780101").Rows(6).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next rowCounter
    End With
End Sub
```